# SQL Server trigger is blocking data to the table

Tags: database, email, triggers

I have a simple trigger to send an email when a record is added to the table, but when the trigger is enabled the table will not populate and the email does not get sent. I am using SQL Server Mgt. Studio V18.8.

Below is the trigger.

```
USE [XXX_STD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Test]  
   ON  [dbo].[Degas]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'SQLMailProfile',
    @recipients = 'xxx@xxx.biz',
    @subject = 'xxx',
    @body = 'xxx',
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

I was able to send a test database email successfully.